# Toshiba Satellite U500 - Totally Damaged LCD

Tags: laptop, hdmi, external-display

I accidentally damaged my Toshiba Satellite U500 laptop which resulted in a totally unusable LCD.  The LCD panel has some cracks on it, and I can only see black & white spots; the laptop frame became broken/bent to where I can partially see inside the PC; the accident disassembled the CD tray, and bent the keyboard frame (which now has a weird hump).

The system is still working though.  It responds to my inputs (eg, turning it on/off, typing my password @ Windows Login, etc).

What I want to do now is to transfer all of my important data from that laptop to my external drive.  But I don't know how since the LCD screen is unreadable.  I know I can connect it to an external monitor or a TV (I have a Samsung 1080p TV) but I don't know how.

- What cable should I purchase to connect the TV?
- Which ports on the laptop and TV should I connect it to?
- Do I need press something while/after connecting it?
- Can I boot my laptop using the TV?

Answer (score 1):

Well, since the laptop seems to be a complete wreck (no output unit, e.g. display), keyboard half working etc., I'd just open it up, get the hdd, put it in some external case (cheap nowadays) and use it as an extra external drive. Copy everything from it, just to be on the safe side, and if it keeps working for a period of time, you've got an extra drive. If it doesn't, throw it along the other laptop components.

Another option is to find an external monitor, an usb keyboard, and use that to "gain control" of the machine again. Then copy everything from the hdd to let's say, an usb stick, little by little, copying it to some other drive.

Or, if the network card & port are still working, use that.

---

To connect them to an external monitor, just find some that has approximately the same resolution as yours.

Comment: Err, I can't really say that the laptop is in total wreck because it seems that only the LCD is not working. The keyboard, touchpad, speakers and the USB ports are working fine. I just want to know what cable to buy and how to connect it to my HDTV then boot using that TV. 
I really need to ditch this laptop for personal reasons.

Comment: That depends on what ports you have available. Here, try this out: http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-connect-your-laptoppccomputer-to-your-tv/ (and tell if that helsp)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the link, I'll just try to find VGA or HMI cable tomorrow but I'm still not sure how to connect it because I know that I need to press/choose something but my laptop's LCD is broken. I'll just try it tomorrow. I need some sleep. :D

Answer (score 1):

three options
1. boot from a livecd, boot into the box, use ssh to control it and copy out the data
2. get an enclosure for a 2.5 inch drive (if its an older IDE based drive it might be dirt cheap). use that to copy the data out
3. get an external monitor. hit the display function key (fn + one of the F keys)until you get an image. In general a VGA cable is a good bet (it looks like a serial port) and one should be attached to most monitors.

Comment: Option 1 seems to be a hassle for me so I might try option 2 or 3. I'll start tomorrow. Thanks :)